# Linq.Max InvalidOperationException (no elements in result)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code:

```
var fullist =  Enumerable.Where<CooldownRecord>(GetCooldowns(petskills), s => (spellId.Contains((uint)s.SpellId) || (SharedIds.Contains((uint)s.SharedId) && s.SharedId != 0)) && s.TimeLeft > 0);
if(fullist.Count() == 0) return 0;
return fullist.Max(s => s.TimeLeft);
```

Most of the time it works. But sometimes it throws InvalidOperationException on fullist.Max. What am I doing wrong here? How can the fullist be empty if there is a check if(fullist.Count() == 0) return 0; ?

Comment: You aren't materializing your query, which means it will execute multiple times. Perhaps you're modifying the source you're querying between the `Where` and `Max`?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll find out that an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown if the input sequence is empty.
That's possible if it changes from the second to the third line.

But i wouldn't execute the query more than once anyway. You can use `DefaultIfEmpty(0)`

```
int maxTimeLeft = GetCooldowns(petskills)
    .Where(s => (spellId.Contains((uint)s.SpellId) || SharedIds.Contains((uint)s.SharedId)) && s.SharedId != 0)) && s.TimeLeft > 0)
    .Select(s => s.TimeLeft)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Max();
return maxTimeLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

For telling exact error, you should share more details but you can try:

```
return GetCooldowns(petskills).Where(s => (spellId.Contains((uint)s.SpellId) || (SharedIds.Contains((uint)s.SharedId) && s.SharedId != 0)) && s.TimeLeft > 0).Select(x => s.TimeLeft)
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                     .Max();
```

And GetCooldowns(petskills) should not return null in any case.
And you should use 'fullist.Any()' instead of 'fullist.Count() == 0' as a good practice.